# Am I using my graphics card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution, gpu

I have a clean installation of Ubuntu 22.04. I can't seem to figure out if I'm actually using my dedicated graphics card. When I plug the monitor into the graphics card output it doesn't display anything - the monitor doesn't even detect a signal. But if I plug it into the motherboard's connector, everything works more or less fine (I get non-native default resolution, but I fixed it temporarily with xrandr - might be unrelated to my question). And most weird thing is, that while it's plugged into the motherboard the nvidia software tells me, that I AM using the dedicated card and so does the `inxi -G` command in the terminal. Is it even possible to utilize the graphics card if the monitor isn't plugged into it? Am I being fooled by the system? Am I just being dumb (I am a Linux newbie, so probably)? Most importantly, how do I fix the output issue - I want to have it plugged into the card, just to be sure. System details alongside with the command outputs attached (as snapshots).

I thought it was obvious, but I also have an integrated GPU.

Results of `inxi -G` :

[image: "inxi -G" output]

System specs:

[image: system specs]

Results of `lshw -c display` :

[image: "lshw -c display" output]

Comment: Why not copy paste the output into your question? This ain't windows..Nonetheless: you have an onboard graphics and a dedicated Nvidia card - your miles may vary which GPU you are using -wherever you plugin your monitors

Comment: Sorry, not a native speaker and i'm not entirely sure what you're saying. Could you reformulate, please? As to why not copy/paste: I'm just used to this, and i already had the images beforehand before i tried askubuntu. Thx

Answer (score 2):

If this is a desktop computer with a discreet GPU, you have to plug the monitor into the GPU to use the GPU.

If the display is plugged into the motherboard then you're not using the discrete GPU.

It's not clear how you installed Ubuntu without a display, but you should have connected the display to the GPU before you started the system installation. If you didn't do that, I suggest that you start over.

Here's the [official tutorial to install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) for reference.

When you are asked, you should elect to install third party drivers and download updates while installing. This should ensure that the appropriate Nvidia drivers are installed during system installation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138269/discussion-on-answer-by-nmath-am-i-using-my-graphics-card).